# Scope of heap memory allocated with new in c++

Tags: c++

New learner for data structure, recently learning Listnode. Got questions.
Define a ListNode:

```
struct ListNode
{
    int val;
    ListNode* next;
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
};
void AddToTail(ListNode** head, int value)
{
    ListNode* nlist = new ListNode(value);
    if(*head == NULL)
    {
        *head = nlist;
    }
    else
    {
        ListNode* p = *head;
        while(p->next != NULL)
        {
            p = p->next;
        }
        p->next = nlist;
    }
    // No need to delete nlist, since the memory allocated by it is already organized by the ListNode.
}

int main()
{
    ListNode* L = new ListNode(5);
    AddToTail(&L, 10);
    ListNode* p = L;
    while(p->next != NULL)
    {
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("Final value is %d.\n", p->val);
    delete L;
}
```

Till now, everything seems ok right? I wonder what if i don't allocate the ListNode memory in heap, that means i don't use new, while i use `ListNode L;` then initialize it manually. The memeory of it is now in stack. The tail added to it is in heap memory. How do i delete the heap memory right now. It seems part of the ListNode memory is in stack and part of it is in heap? Am i correctly understood?

Comment: You're leaking memory regardless. Nothing is deleting the node created by `AddToTail`.

Comment: Don't mix memory allocated on the stack and in the heap in a container without tracking who is responsible for deleting the objects.

Comment: @Rotem Then how can i delete the tail added by `AddToTail`?

Comment: ALL dynamically allocated objects (e.g. created by a `new` expression) must be explicitly released (e.g. with a corresponding `delete` expression) and no other objects should be explicitly released. That is true regardless of how you mix up objects "in stack" (incorrect description for an object of automatic storage duration) with "in heap" (incorrect description of pointer to dynamically allocated object). If you mix use of dynamic memory allocation and objects of automatic storage duration, *you* are responsible for ensuring only the dynamically allocated ones are released.

Comment: @BigEd Depends how you define responsibility in your data structure. Something must be in charge of calling `delete` on `new`ed objects. One scenario might be that each node deletes the subsequent node before deleting itself, triggering a recursive deletion. Another scenario is that you delegate that responsibility to the user of the data structure, and if you do, it might make more sense to also delegate the responsibility of allocating the `ListNode` to the user as well.

Comment: @Peter, Thank you for the answer. Right, i got the idea.

Comment: @Rotem Thank you, i now got more insight of how should the whole structure work.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, it doesn't really matter whether `L` is dynamically allocated or not. That's by-the-by. In fact there's no reason here to dynamically allocate it.

What matters is the ownership and lifetime of the nodes that it manages. These are dynamically allocated, so you will need a destructor inside `ListNode` that unlinks and de-allocates the nodes.

There's nothing wrong with "mixing" storage duration — that's what you're doing every time you instantiate a `std::vector<int>`, for example. You just need to ensure that anything *owning* dynamically allocated data has the capability to clean up after itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need some delete function like this

```
    void DeleteList(ListNode** head)
    {
        ListNode* p = *head;
        while(p != NULL)
        {
            ListNode *t = p->next;
            delete p;
            p = t;
        }
    }

    // and call it in main:

    printf("Final value is %d.\n", p->val);
    DeleteList(&L);
```

But it is better to immediately define all these operations in a special class, such as List:

```
class List
{
private:
    ListNode  *head;
public:   
    List() : head(NULL){}
    ~List() { Clear(); }
    void AddToTail(int value);
    void Clear();      
};

void List::AddToTail(int value)
{
    ListNode* nlist = new ListNode(value);
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = nlist;
    }
    else
    {
        ListNode* p = head;
        while(p->next != NULL)
        {
            p = p->next;
        }
        p->next = nlist;
    }
}


void List::Clear()
{
    ListNode* p = head;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        ListNode *t = p->next;
        delete p;
        p = t;
    }
    head = NULL;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
List lst;
lst.AddToTail(5);
lst.AddToTail(10);
lst.AddToTail(20);
lst.AddToTail(30);
lst.Clear();
```